# Applying class to an element - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a web page that has a large number of tables. The JQuery script processes each row and decides what CSS style needs to be applied to it. I am using this snippet to apply a class to the table cell

```
$myElem.parents('td').eq(0).attr('class', 'requiredClass');
```

Functionally, it works as expected. However, in IE7.0, it takes 16ms to run this. Given the number of rows on the page, this adds up pretty quickly to atleast half a second.

How can I make this run faster?

Comment: is the selector supposed to be "get the top parent <td> for $myElem" ? Are you using nested tables?

Comment: The table structure is something like this: 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td (apply style)><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
The myElem has reference to the checkbox, and the style should be applied to it's <td>

Comment: see my answer for the most performant way to do this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399893/applying-class-to-an-element-jquery/1400087#1400087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In light of your comment in the Question, this should be the most performant

```
$Elem.parent('td').addClass('requiredClass');
```

This uses [`parent()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent) instead of [`parents()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents), the former only looking at the *immediate* parent, the latter looking at all parents up to but excluding the root node.

The `<td>` is most likely superfluous in `parent()` too as it acts to filter out those parent nodes that are not a `<td>` element. Since you are processing each row at a time, I would imagine that you can guarantee that the parent in each case is a `<td>` and therefore I would remove that filter too. So it becomes

```
$Elem.parent().addClass('requiredClass');
```

It may be faster still if, rather than processing each row at a time, you could identify the set of rows that need to have a certain class applied to the `<td>` in question and then issue one selector to the add the class. This might not be possible, it depends on the check being performed, but just a thought nonetheless.

**EDIT:**

You say you need to remove an unknown class before adding the new one but don't know what the class name will be in each case. Calling removeClass() without a class name string parameter will remove all classes. In case you didn't know, Elements can have multiple classes defined, each one separated by a space, for example, `<td class="class1 class">`.  jQuery's addClass() command will ensure that each new class name added will be separated from any others by a space. So, the selector may now look like

```
$Elem.parent().removeClass().addClass('requiredClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using addClass method.

```
$("#ID").addClass("newclass");
```

And use removeClass when you want to remove it.

The problem might be that handling class as attribute may not be fast in IE (this is my guess as I don't use IE).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$myElem.parents('td').eq(0).addClass('requiredClass');
```

Comment: The element already has a css class that is unknown before this statement is executed. So, in theory, I should first do a removeClass and then a addClass. However, I do not know the name of the class to do a removeClass

Comment: This is cleaner, but will be slower still.

Comment: @unknown - calling removeClass() without a classname parameter will remove all classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [addClass() method](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass#class), it adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.

```
$Elem.parent('td').addClass('requiredClass');
```

Comment: The element already has a css class that is unknown before this statement is executed. So, in theory, I should first do a removeClass and then a addClass. However, I do not know the name of the class to do a removeClass

Comment: Its not strictly necessary to remove the first class. You can have more than one class defined on an element. `<a class="external_link highlight">asdf</a>` would be styled as **both** `external_link` and `highlight`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with calling the `eq` function.  It appears you only want the first `td` so below is a much more appropriate selector. I am also using addClass function to set the class name, as opposed to using `attr`

```
$myElem.parent('td:first').removeClass().addClass('requiredClass');
```

Comment: The element already has a css class that is unknown before this statement is executed. So, in theory, I should first do a removeClass and then a addClass. However, I do not know the name of the class to do a removeClass

Comment: And when I use $myElem.parents('td:first').attr('class', 'requiredclass'); I don't see an improvement in performance

Comment: Its not strictly necessary to remove the first class. You can have more than one class defined on an element. `<a class="external_link highlight">asdf</a>` would be styled as both `external_link` and `highlight`.

Comment: I have made the appropriate changes.  I also changed from parents to parent, which was original intention.